# How to connect two routers and subnets?

Tags: router, routing, subnet

I know this is very basic question, but I don't have prior experience of setting network environments with multiple routers and no matter what I try I can't get the configuration working.

So, I have two routers, A and B. A is a dumb fellow (no DDNS, VPN, etc. fancy features) provided by my ISP and its duty is to bridge PPPoE to router B (ASUS RT-AC68U) and provide telephone access (not possible with B). A must be connected directly to WAN. PPPoE bridge works fine, meaning that I can access internet from Subnet B and DDNS in router B works. However, I can't access either Internet nor subnet B from subnet A. `ping 10.0.0.1` from laptop throws `Transmit error: code 1231`, and `ping 10.0.2.1` from PC throws `Destination net unreachable.`

Router B has DHCP server running, whereas A does not, in order to make sure two DHCP servers don't mess up each other.

I tried adding static route to B (10.0.2.0/255.255.255.0 gateway: 10.0.2.1), but it didn't seem to work. I also tried adding static route to A (10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0 gateway: 10.0.0.1), but it didn't work either.

What kind of routing, gateway, etc. settings do I have to set in each router in order to get access between the subnets? Access to Internet from subnet A is not necessary. Instructions preferably in noob format, as I'm not expert when it comes to routers and routing.

Routing table of B:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
<external 1.>   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 ppp0
10.0.1.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun21
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
10.0.1.0        10.0.1.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
<external 2.>   *               255.255.0.0     U        0      0        0 MAN0 eth0
default         <external 1.>   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 ppp0
```

The topology:

[image: here]

Comment: I [already explained you](http://superuser.com/a/1155590/493903) that writing "router 10.0.0.1" makes no sense, because a router to be a router must be connected at least to two IP networks and it must have at least two different addresses from these separate networks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Router B is connected to internet via PPPoE connection, has thus public IP and private IP as shown.

Comment: No, each of your routers on your diagram has **one** address. While Router A should have **four** and Router B should have **three**.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @grawity Of course it's a nonsense from the configuration point of view. But for the diagram to be valid and understandable, it must list four addresses.

Comment: Router B does have public IP, because naturally without it DDNS wouldn't work and PC, which I'm currently writing these message from, couldn't be connected to Internet.

Comment: @grawity It wouldn't, because if OP tried to draw a clear and concise diagram, he would find most of the mistakes himself. If there are no four addresses, then OP should delete the arrows. I already explained it in simple words to OP under his other question, but got ignored.

Comment: @grawity I don't understand your intention replying to my comments. I point out the diagram is incoherent. Do you think the diagram is ok? A router with four physical interfaces connected, and one IP address defined? What does it route then? What are you trying to explain me? That the diagram is fine? Because if anything else, then you are missing the intention of my comment and you are starting unrelated threads.

Comment: @Kitanotori: Could you post the routing table of A, or at least a screenshot of its LAN settings?

Comment: @techraf: I suppose I'm trying to say that routers are also capable of acting as L2 bridges with no routing involved. (That's how most home "wireless routers" work – they assign an IP address/subnet to the LAN bridge as a whole, not to each individual port.)

Comment: @grawity Unfortunately A does not have UI for showing routing table. Does netstat -rn from laptop connected to it suffice?

Comment: @grawity Thank you. I know that. I don't find it related to my comment (nor this question) in any way. And if you look at the diagram, you will see that Router A should have four IP addresses: one on 10.0.2.0, one on the WAN interface to ONU, one on the IP network connected to Router B (10.0.0.0 ?), and one on the PPPoE interface. I see no L2 bridging being used here and still I don't see how your comments relate to mine. Are they supposed to contradict, support, extend?

Comment: @techraf: ISPs which use PPPoE practically _never_ allow assigning IP addresses directly on the WAN interface – they only allow PPPoE packets and not IP. So the only "WAN" address would be on the PPPoE interface. (And since it was mentioned that router A has PPPoE-relay enabled, only _router B_ would have the actual PPPoE interface. I assume that's the `ppp0` in the posted routing table.)

Comment: @grawity Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Since router B is not connect to a WAN, why is its WAN port connected?

Answer (score 3):

I like this question, old though it might be.

Some conceptual items:

- Routers should typically be drawn *between* networks because they provide a "route" (or path) from one to the other.
- They can be connected to as many networks as they are capable of, and they will have an IP address on each.
- You don't need more than one physical link between routers, to answer the implicit question related to the two links between router A and router B.
- Any physical link between two routers should be represented as a network on the layer-3 diagram (it can be a network that other hosts or routers are connected to).

In your diagram, I would place router A between the Internet and subnet A.

I would place router B between subnet A and subnet B, meaning that subnet A is also used as a routing network between subnet B and the Internet.

In order for the routing network to work out correctly, router B must be configured with router A as its default route to the Internet.  Also, router A must be configured to recognize router B as the correct direction for traffic to subnet B.

That probably looks like:

- Router B:

  - IP1: 10.0.0.1/24 netmask: 255.255.255.0
  - IP2: 10.0.2.2/24 netmask: 255.255.255.0
  - Route: Net: 0.0.0.0/0 [default], gateway: 10.0.2.1/24
  - Note that the networks 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24 are defined implicitly and are local to this router.  Only the Internet needs an explicit route.
- Router A:

  - IP1: [Internet IP via PPPoE]
  - IP2: 10.0.2.1/24 netmask 255.255.255.0
  - Route: Net: 0.0.0.0/0 [default], gateway: PPPoE
  - Route: Net: 10.0.0.0/24, gateway: 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I could think to accomplish this would be to divide the IP range allotted to you from your ISP. Most private home addressing spaces start from 192.168.1.0/24. This router should be reachable by the Internet and other devices in your home such as smart TVs, Voice Assistants, video game consoles and so on. The outer most layer of your network is traditionally the most untrusted. However, if you do have sensitive client information on workstations and host devices in your home network you may want to give them a little more security. You can do this by configuring another router on your network to run on a different sub net. This will take a little networking knowledge. The outermost routers gateway will probably be 192.168.1.0/24. You could create a different subnet for your second router to run on and provide more security for important devices. You could configure your second router with a sub net of 192.168.1.0/28 with your broadcast IP being 192.168.1.15/28. Or you could use another subnet such as 192.168.1.48/28. You could even further segregate your network with an additional router with a sub net of 192.168.1.64/29. The most important devices need to be on the innermost subnets while not so important services can stay on your gateway router.

Answer (score -1):

IP setup is wrong rout A 10.0.2.1 router B 10.0.2.2 router B connection wan to LAN remove LAN to LAN
both routers should have same subnet and DHCP running

Comment: if its to extend your network then one router should use DHCP server up and running the other should get the IP from it in that case remove wan to LAN and make LAN to LAN  but than its not a subnet. you find more info if you search how to setup routers in cascade